# GO: Why does dialing from the address on which the client is listening not work, but the opposite does?

Tags: go, server, client, client-server

I wonder why dialing from the address on which the client is also listening does not work (**`Version A`**) but listening on the connection address the client is dialing to the server does actually work (**`Version B`**)?!

Can someone explain this to me. `Go` is new to me and I still learning a lot of things.

Here is an example:

Server Programm:

```
package main

import . "fmt"
import "net"
import "os"

func main() {
    Println("server")

    var listener, listenerError = net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")

    if listenerError != nil {

        Println(listenerError)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {
        con, _ := listener.Accept() // I don't care about the error in this example
        Printf("LocalAddr: %v\n", con.LocalAddr())
        Printf("RemoteAddr: %v\n", con.RemoteAddr())
    }
}
```

Client version A (not working):

```
package main

import "net"
import . "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {

    var listener, listenerError = net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:0")

    if listenerError != nil {

        Println(listenerError)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var dialer = new(net.Dialer)
    dialer.LocalAddr = listener.Addr()

    con, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {

        // dial tcp 127.0.0.1:60229->127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use
        Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    Printf("LocalAddr: %v\n", con.LocalAddr())
    Printf("RemoteAddr: %v\n", con.RemoteAddr())
}
```

Client version B (working):

```
package main

import "net"
import . "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    Println("client")

    con, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {

        Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    // magic happens here
    var listener, listenerError = net.Listen("tcp", con.LocalAddr().String())

    if listenerError != nil {

        Println(listenerError)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Println("LISTENING")
    conn, _ := listener.Accept() // will accept on con.LocalAddr()
    Printf("LocalAddr: %v\n", conn.LocalAddr())
    Printf("RemoteAddr: %v\n", conn.RemoteAddr())
}
```

Comment: This isn't a go issue, you can't bind multiple sockets to the same address. Why does the client need a listener, and what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to build a network were clients will represent some graph (like a p2p network but not every client knows every other client). First all clients will connect to the server, the server will create the graph and then send the clients the id and network address of their neighbor clients. This is why I want my clients to be able to listen. I could use two ports for the clients (one for the connection to the client and the second for listening), but I thoughts it would be better to use a single address/port.

Comment: That's fine, but you still can't dial from the same address you've bound to the listener. There's no problem using 2 ports.

Comment: Im still confused why does the opposite work? I can tell the listener to listen on an address I used the dialer.

Comment: Ok I think I'll go with the two ports solution and transmit the addresses for the listeners which the server will forward to the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Version B" works as a side effect of the Go's POSIX default of setting `SO_REUSEADDR`, which will allow binding to an `addr:port` pair even if it's in use by an existing connection. The 2 sockets can be differentiated, because the established connection is identified by the 4-tuple of `(LocalAddr, LocalPort, RemoteAddr, RemotePort)`.

"Version A" doesn't work, because when setting up the connection it needs to call `bind` to set the requested local address, and there is already a listening socket bound to that port.

There's no need to try and exploit this loophole, and you should use 2 ports for your client and server connections.